# Slice out Nth element in nested dictionary values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I wish you all good first winter day tomorrow. Though, for my day to be good, i need to get my nested dictionaries right...

DATA. (dictionary where keys are tuples, and values are 2 dimensional numpy arrays)

```
lst = [(0), (1), (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4)]
array = np.random.random((5,2))
dictionary = dict(zip(lst, array))
```

QUESTION. How do I delete first element in dictionary values (first dimension of an array)? Or how do I slice dictionary, so that only second element in values remain (second dimension of an array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly this could do your job:

```
lst = [(0), (1), (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4)]
array = np.random.random((5,2))
dictionary = dict(zip(lst, array))
element = 0
dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.keys(), map(lambda x: np.delete(x, element), dictionary.values())))
```